# Filling out a web form using Method Post

Tags: html, forms, post

I need help understanding why using form actions don't work on certain websites. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/5549c/2/) is an example, and the code is below. I'm trying to fill in a text area, but it won't work. I'm sure there's a simple rule that I'm forgetting, any help would be appreciated.

```
<form action="http://www.boxer.senate.gov/en/contact/policycomments.cfm" method="post" target="_blank" >
<input type="submit" name="firstName" value="test">
</form>
```

Comment: errr... are you trying to flood some senator's inbox? :-)

Comment: I guess you have to use firebug to see what's being sent when you submit the form in the site, so you can find all the necessary variables and headers used in a regular form submission.

Comment: of course not! I'm simply curious about pre-populate fields, and that website was a unique example where it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because certain websites reject posted data which did not originate from their server. The reason they do this is because it reduces spam. There is nothing wrong with the HTML.

```
# block comment spam by denying access to no-referrer requests
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !.*yourwebsite.com.* [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ^http://the-site-where-you-want-to-send-spammers.com/$ [R=301,L]
```

An easier method would be a two part form.

Comment: This makes sense, thank you. Shouldn't this be a standard though? There seem to be quite a few sites which don't prevent this from happening. Also, what do you mean by a two part form?

Comment: Twitter certainly wants to allow it because it gets other websites to send them traffic. A two part form would be submit page 1, then submit page 2. Page 2 only comes up with a post from page 1, and a  hidden text field <input type="hidden" name="id" value="provided by server"> can insure it was from the same user. The problem with the referer method in the post is HTTPS servers don't provide the referer.

Answer (score 1):

you need to use a language to then return the data.

If you send this form to a .php file... then within the php specify:

```
$firstName = $_POST['firstName'];
$echo $firstName;
```

It will print 'test' to the document window.